# Do we need to convert single elements of j to a list when the overall result of j is a list anyway?

Tags: r, data.table

### Background

A basic property of `data.table` is that

> "As long as `j` returns a list, each element of the list becomes a column in the resulting data.table."

This is shown e.g. in an example from `?data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
DT[, c(.N, lapply(.SD, sum)), by=x]
```

Here the integer `.N` is `c`oncatenated with the list resulting from `lapply`, and the overall result is a list, i.e. `.N` is *implicitly* coerced to a list element (according to the coercion hierarchy described in `?c`)

What caught my attention was the example used in both `?data.table` and `.SD` where, in contrast to above, the 'non-list' part of `j` is *explicitly* converted to a list:

```
DT[, c(.(y=max(y)), lapply(.SD, min)), by=rleid(v), .SDcols=v:b]
```

It is not immediately obvious to me why the single number resulting from `y=max(y)` in this example is converted to a list (`.()`) when it will be converted to a list element anyway, following the `c`oncatenation with a list (`lapply(.SD.,` ).

---

### explicit `list` not needed?

Here's a small example where `max(y)` and `sum` of all variables are calculated by a grouping variable. The `str`ucture and the result of the calculations are indeed the same, both when explicitly converting the 'non-list' result in `j` to a list, and when not doing so:

```
dt <- data.table(grp = rep(c("a", "b"), 2:3), x = 1:5, y = 2:6)

# - structure of j
dt[ , str(c(.(ymax = max(y)), lapply(.SD, sum))), by = grp]
dt[ , str(c(ymax = max(y), lapply(.SD, sum))), by = grp]

# - result of j
dt[ , c(.(ymax = max(y)), lapply(.SD, sum)), by = grp]
dt[ , c(ymax = max(y), lapply(.SD, sum)), by = grp]

# ...both give the same result:
```

Thus, in these examples, explicitly converting the non-list part of `j` to a list  seems redundant. So is it really needed? Perhaps next example with `.N` provides a clue.

---

### explicit `list` needed with `.N`!

Is this case the 'non-list' part of `j` is `.N`, otherwise `j` is the same as above.

The `str`ucture of `j` is the same, both with and without explicit conversion of `.N` to a list in `j`:

```
dt[ , str(c(.(n = .N), lapply(.SD, sum))), by = grp]
dt[ , str(c(n = .N, lapply(.SD, sum))), by = grp]

# List of 3
#  $ n: int 2
#  $ x: int 3
#  $ y: int 5
# List of 3
#  $ n: int 3
#  $ x: int 12
#  $ y: int 15
```

**~~>** Note that according to `str`, in both cases the "`.N` variable" has the name which was set in `j`, "n".

However, if `.N` is not explicitly "`list`ed" in `j`, the name of `.N` remains the default "N" (see `?.N`) in the results:

```
dt[ , c(.(n = .N), lapply(.SD, sum)), by = grp]
#    grp n  x  y
# 1:   a 2  3  5
# 2:   b 3 12 15

dt[ , c(n = .N, lapply(.SD, sum)), by = grp]
#    grp N  x  y
# 1:   a 2  3  5
# 2:   b 3 12 15
```

---

### Question

Of course my question is not about trying to avoid typing the three characters `.()`, but to understand the fundamentals of how `j` can/should be specified.

Is the default name of `.N` (as shown above) the exception which warrants the use of explicit `list`, always, just to be on the safe side? Are there other pitfalls which I have overlooked?

Comment: Probably just a bug. Fwiw, I always wrap with .(), though, so I don't have to think about how vectors and lists concatenate together.

Comment: agree with Frank; if anything I'm surprised the latter case didn't come out named as `V1`

Answer (score 3):

First, thanks to @Frank for pointing out that the behaviour of the name of `.N` might be a bug. Although a minor issue itself ([posted one though](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/2165)), it indeed seems like it the was the cause of my more general confusion of the use of `list` in `j`.

I made some further simple tests on `.N` and its name, which suggest some potential inconsistencies. FWIW, I thought I might just as well share them here (too long for comment).

#### 1: The name of `.N` in result

1a: `.N` is autonamed 'N' when (1) using `.N` only, (2) `.N` with `by`, or (3) `.N` with `lapply` and `by`.

1b: `.N` is autonamed 'V1', instead of 'N' when using (1) `.N` with `lapply`, or (2) `list(.N)` with `lapply`

```
# 1a: .N is autonamed 'N'

# .N only
dt[ , .(.N)]
#    N
# 1: 5

# .N + by
dt[ , .(.N), by = grp]
#   grp N
# 1:  a 2
# 2:  b 3

# .N + lapply + by 
dt[ , c(.N, lapply(.SD, max)), by = grp]
#    grp N x y
# 1:   a 2 2 3 
# 2:   b 3 5 6


# 1b: .N is autonamed V1, instead of N

# .N + lapply
dt[ , c(.N, lapply(.SD, max))]
#    V1 grp x y
# 1:  5   b 5 6

# list(.N) + lapply
d[ , c(.(.N), lapply(.SD, max))]
#    V1 grp x  y
# 1:  5   2 5 10
```

#### 2: renaming `.N`

2a: `list(.N)` is not needed when using `.N` with `lapply`

2b: `list(.N)` is needed when using `.N` with `lapply` and `by`.

```
# 2a: list(.N) not needed

# .N + lapply
dt[ , c(n = .N, lapply(.SD, max))]
#    n grp x y
# 1: 5   b 5 6


# 2b: list(.N) needed

# .N + lapply + by
dt[ , c(.(n = .N), lapply(.SD, max)), by = grp]
#    grp n x y
# 1:   a 2 2 3
# 2:   b 3 5 6
```

---