# data.table : column name not working with j = c() and by

Tags: r, data.table

Difficult to formulate my question (hence difficult to search efficiently in the archives...). The code below should be clear.

Why in the second command the last column name of the output is not "nb_ob" ? `c(lapply(.SD, mean), nb_obs = .N)` should provide a named list with 4 elements that should become a column in the final result.

Curiously `c(lapply(.SD[,1:4], mean), nb_obs = .N)` (third command) provides the intended result. If I remove the `by` argument (last command) I also obtain the expected column name (with a warning for the character column "Species").

Code run with data.table_1.10.4, R version 3.4.1 for Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS (I can provide more if needed)

```
iris <- data.table(iris)
iris[, c(lapply(.SD, mean), nb_obs = .N), by = Species] # 2nd command
#       Species Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width  N
# 1:     setosa        5.006       3.428        1.462       0.246 50
# 2: versicolor        5.936       2.770        4.260       1.326 50
# 3:  virginica        6.588       2.974        5.552       2.026 50

iris[, c(lapply(.SD[,1:4], mean), nb_obs = .N), by = Species] # 3rd command
#       Species Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width nb_obs
# 1:     setosa        5.006       3.428        1.462       0.246     50
# 2: versicolor        5.936       2.770        4.260       1.326     50
# 3:  virginica        6.588       2.974        5.552       2.026     50

iris[, c(lapply(.SD, mean), nb_obs = .N)] # Fourth command
#    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species nb_obs
# 1:     5.843333    3.057333        3.758    1.199333      NA    150
```

Comment: I think It is related to GForce. When I Turn off optimizaiton with `options(datatable.optimize = 0L)`, the 2nd command will also give same output as 3rd. This might be due to that using `.SD[, 1:4]` has a similar effect as turing GForce. Anyway, for this job, I would try `iris[, c(lapply(.SD, mean), list(nb_obs = .N)), by = Species]`.

Comment: I guess the `nb_obs` is ignored when coercing `.N` to a list during optimization.

Comment: As far as I know, mt1022 is right about it being thanks to optimization overriding names. I filed a related issue recently https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/2311

Comment: A similar question of mine: [Do we need to convert single elements of `j` to a list when the overall result of `j` is a list anyway?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43979990/do-we-need-to-convert-single-elements-of-j-to-a-list-when-the-overall-result-of), and the issue I posted afterwards: [Possible inconsistencies in the autonaming and renaming of .N](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/2165). @mt1022 Thanks for your suggestion about GForce.

Comment: OK, thank you. I understand that this behavior is not the intended behavior (it was not obvious for me as I  am a real beginner with data.table). I hope there will be a fix. In the meanwhile the solution of @mt1022 with `c(lapply(.SD, mean), list(nb_obs = .N))` is useful.

Comment: @mt1022 has the correct syntax for concatenating lists

Comment: @MichaelChirico It's always nice to be explicit, but see also the `?data.table` examples which use the implicit coercion with `c()` (see also the various attempts in my similar question, linked to above). Cheers

Comment: @Henrik good point. Perhaps not the best examples in `?data.table` -- attempting to get implicit coercion to work tends to fail miserably for me, so I stick with explicit `list`ing

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue in `data.table` project backlog raised based on this question:

- https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/2311

---

*This answer is based on @Frank's comment above.*